# Does javascript subresource integrity check protect from client-side editing?

Tags: javascript, security

The question says it all. Does the use of subresource integrity checks foil execution of javascript which has been edited locally (say in the browser's debug window)?

Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Don't trust the client when the client stands to gain advantage from modifying data - remember a malicious client could simply remove the subresource integrity directives entirely. Unless you're trying to protect the user against [self-XSS](http://inpursuitoflaziness.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/the-battle-against-self-xss.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity):

> Browsers handle SRI by doing the following:
>
> When a browser encounters a `<script>` or `<link>` element with an
>   integrity attribute, before executing the script or before applying
>   any stylesheet specified by the `<link>` element, the browser must first
>   compare the script or stylesheet to the expected hash given in the
>   integrity value.
>
> If the script or stylesheet doesn’t match its
>   associated integrity value, then the browser must refuse to execute
>   the script or apply the stylesheet, and must instead return a network
>   error indicating that fetching of that script or stylesheet failed.

So no, it does not protect from malicious code being executed via console, since that wont affect the loaded files in any way.

Comment: Hi Schlaus, can I ask where the hash is stored to check against the script integrity hash?
There has to be 2 hashes, 1 on the script/link. Other is on..?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK The objective is to verify that the linked file has not been changed. A hash value will be calculated from the file, by the browser, once it has been downloaded. If the calculated hash does not match the one provided in the link, that means the file has been changed and the contents will not be executed.